# Convert ZoneId and timestamp to formatted date string in java 8, considering daylight saving time

Tags: java, timezone, dst, java-time, datetimeoffset

I have some logs and each log message has a timestamp, so I would like to display log message's timestamp in a user-friendly format in Java 8 with the `java.time` API.

For example, let's say that I have :

- a `List<Long>` that stores all my log timestamps.
- a `ZoneId` that describes the zone I want to use to convert timestamps. Actually, it's `Europe/Paris` so I have to consider Daylight Saving Time (DST for short).
- a `DateTimeFormatter` that describes the string format I want.

Then, I would like to convert each timestamps in my list to a String that describes this timestamp in my zone, knowing that the offset *may differ* between 2 timestamps due to DST.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Are these timestamps a count of seconds/milliseconds/etc. from 1970-01-01T00:00:00 in UTC?

Comment: What have you tried? We can guide you much better from your best attempt (even if it is failed) than from no code at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [java.time](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API's [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class automatically takes care of [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). As such, here is a sample implementation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> timestamps = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> result = timestamps.stream()
            .map(timestamp -> convert(timestamp))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}

public static String convert(Long epochMilli) {
    Instant now = Instant.ofEpochMilli(epochMilli);
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris");
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, zoneId);
    DateTimeFormatter isoDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
    return zonedDateTime.format(isoDateFormatter);
}
```

Comment: To explain, a `java.time.Instant` is always in UTC. The time zone `ZoneId` is then applied to get a `ZonedDateTime`. We still have the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but viewed through the lens of some particular region‘s wall-clock time.

Comment: `Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)` could be replaced with  `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: The reason I tend to avoid `Collectors.toList()` is because the documentation states:
`There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the {@code List} returned; if more control over the returned {@code List} is required, use {@link #toCollection(Supplier)}.` It is a little more verbose, but it allows me to be sure what I'm dealing with.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Comment: Good answer and interesting comments. @Synch, I suggest you incorporate the comments by you and assylias into your Answer, to provide more info about the options.